# Cant use mysql using container password not working

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have created mysql container using docker but its not accpeting the set password.

```
root@5b4f1a35c7b8:/# mysql -uroot -ppassword
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Code from dockerfile

```
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: 'png-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/docker-compose-lamp/bin/mysql/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: x_muti_site
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: If you remove all the volumes, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Yes. tried docker-compose down -v

Comment: I mean to not have them in the docker-compose.yml